# Reading and Combining Excel Time Series in Matlab- Maintaining Order

Tags: excel, matlab, time-series, portfolio, xlsread

I have the following code to read off time series data (contained in sheets 5 to 19 in an excel workbook). Each worksheet is titled "TS" followed by the number of the time series. The process works fine apart from one thing- when I study the returns I find that all the time series are shifted along by 5. i.e. TS 6 becomes the 11th column in the "returns" data and TS 19 becomes the 5th column, TS 15 becomes the 1st column etc. I need them to be in the same order that they are read- such that TS 1 is in the 1st column, TS 2 in the 2nd etc.
This is a problem because I read off the titles of the worksheets ("AssetList") which maintain their actual order throughout subsequent codes. Therefore when I recombine the titles and the returns I find that they do not match. This complicates further manipulation when, for example column 4 is titled "TS 4" but actually contains the data of  TS 18.
Is there something in this code that I have wrong?

```
XL='TimeSeries.xlsx';

formatIn = 'dd/mm/yyyy';
formatOut = 'mmm-dd-yyyy';


Bounds=3;
[Bounds,~] = xlsread(XL,Bounds);
```

% Determine the number of worksheets in the xls-file:

```
FirstSheet=5;
[~,AssetList] = xlsfinfo(XL);
lngth=size(AssetList,2);
AssetList(:,1:FirstSheet-1)=[];
```

% Loop through the number of sheets and RETRIEVE VALUES

```
merge_count = 1; 

for I=FirstSheet:lngth



    [FundValues, ~, FundSheet] = xlsread(XL,I);
```

% EXTRACT DATES AND DATA AND COMBINE
    % (TO REMOVE UNNECCESSARY TEXT IN ROWS 1 TO 4)

```
Fund_dates_data = FundSheet(4:end,1:2);
FundDates = cellstr(datestr(datevec(Fund_dates_data(:,1),...
                                    formatIn),formatOut));
FundData = cell2mat(Fund_dates_data(:,2));
% CREATE TIME SERIES FOR EACH FUND

    Fundts{I}=fints(FundDates,FundData,['Fund',num2str(I)]);

    if merge_count == 2
        Port = merge(Fundts{I-1},Fundts{I},'DateSetMethod','Intersection');
    end
    if merge_count > 2
        Port = merge(Port,Fundts{I},'DateSetMethod','Intersection');
    end
    merge_count = merge_count + 1;

end
```

% ANALYSE PORTFOLIO

```
Returns=tick2ret(Port);
q = Portfolio;
q = q.estimateAssetMoments(Returns)
[qassetmean, qassetcovar] = q.getAssetMoments
```

Comment: So are you saying that `FundDates` and `FundData` are misaligned in every loop iteration? Also do you have access to Matlab 2013b? Because then you should check out the new [`readtable`](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2013/09/10/introduction-to-the-new-matlab-data-types-in-r2013b/#fe5c445a-1e68-4a44-ab40-d9cc90438539) command as an alternative to `xlsread`.

Comment: I have 2011. It aligns the dates rows and the time series rows correctly. But just shifts the columns along. It wouldn't be too much of an issue but the sheet "bounds" can only contain data in the order of the worksheets in the workbook. This causes the wrong upper/ lower bounds to be specified to the wrong time series- e.g. bounds for TS 1 are applied to TS 5, and so on.

Comment: It's still tough to follow exactly where this misalignment occurs. Perhaps you could add to your question exactly what is misaligned in term of the variable names you use in your code?

Comment: Thanks Dan, I have clarified the question a little more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably due to `merge`. By default, it sorts columns alphabetically.  Unfortunately, as your naming pattern is "FundN", this means that, for example, Fund10 will normally be sorted before Fund9.  So as you're looping over I from 5 to 19, you will have `Fund10`, through `Fund19`, followed by `Fund4` through `Fund9`.

One way of solving this would to be always use zero padding (Fund01, Fund02, etc) so that alphabetical order and numerical order are the same.  Alternatively, force it to stay in the order you read/merge the data by setting SortColumns to 0:

`Port = merge(Port,Fundts{I},'DateSetMethod','Intersection','SortColumns',0);`

Comment: Thanks nkjt. I have used TS naming convention only to illustrate the point. In actual fact the names of the worksheets are words- the names of the funds. Do you suggest, however, that 'SortColumns' would still work in this case?

Comment: `'SortColumns', 0` basically just sets it to no sorting - so it should keep the columns in the order to which they are read/added.  (Tested using your ['Fund',num2str(I)] example).